# Run junit tests written in Kotlin with @category annotation

Tags: junit, kotlin

I have got a question.
Is it possible to annotate Junit tests, written in Kotlin,
by @Category with spaces in interface name? 
I want to have something like this:

```
@Test
@Category(`Kotlin interface`::class)
fun `Test with spaces`() {
```

Now I receive an exception

Comment: Please always provide the error message / exception stack trace. People can't help you without knowing what error exactly do you get

Answer (score 0):

Even though class names with spaces are allowed in Kotlin, they go against the naming convention, which is PascalCase or UpperCamelCase if you will. I just tested this with the latest JUnit 4 and it doesn't work.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56217:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.foo.bar.http.BarHTTPApplicationTest,systemInfoGET

java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: Signature Parse error: expected '<' or ';' but got  
    Remaining input:  Tests;

    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(SignatureParser.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parsePackageNameAndSimpleClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:310)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:289)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:485)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSig(SignatureParser.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:436)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:599)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:597)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getDeclaredAnnotations(Executable.java:588)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:630)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:207)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.getAnnotations(FrameworkMethod.java:187)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.addToAnnotationLists(TestClass.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:65)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

So, maybe one day it will be possible, but not right now.